# Power BI :: calculate AVERAGE of previous 30 days

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, measure

StackOveflow helped me create this beautiful metrics: the delta between what we pay and what we could have paid.

In the picture you can see how we took an action on the 31 of January 2023 and after that date we calculate the delta of it (the purple area):

[image]

But that fixed amount is based on the date 31/01/2013:

```
Realised Savings prod Fixed Amount = 
 var fixedAmount = CALCULATE([Realised Savings prod], FILTER(ALL(Data), Data[UsageDate]= DATE(2023,1,31)))

 RETURN  IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Realised Savings prod])) && MIN(Data[UsageDate])>= DATE(2023,1,31), fixedAmount)
```

Instead I would like to set that bar on the `AVERAGE` of the 30 days previous of the 31/01/2023. Because this will give a more realistic metrics.

ChatGPT suggests:

```
Realised Savings prod Fixed Amount =
VAR StartDate = DATE(2023, 1, 31) - 30
VAR FixedAmount =
    CALCULATE(
        [Realised Savings prod],
        FILTER(ALL(Data), Data[UsageDate] >= StartDate && Data[UsageDate] <= DATE(2023, 1, 31))
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK([Realised Savings prod])) && MIN(Data[UsageDate]) >= StartDate,
        FixedAmount
    )
```

But that just brakes the lines of the chart :(

Here the files:

- [.pbix](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwioDIJzDoA4hiIJA?e=sjKLEr)
- [.xslx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArldK_gE2gPUkcwhkUIUR5Bz9ZjXcg?e=vcyFqh)

Comment: So you can't get ChatGPT to solve your problem, THEN you come to us?

Comment: @SolarMike , isn't this what StackOverflow is made for?

Comment: So why waste time with ChatGPT? Never seen anywhere a post saying ChatGPT wrote this fantastic code…

Comment: Well, before upsetting people on StackOverflow is good to bang your head on the problem and try to solve it by yourself. If you cannot solve it by yourself you pass to the next step which is trying to solve it through ChatGPT. I saw that the code was good and the DAX code was accepted by PowerBI but unfortunately the line chart was behaving unproperly. 
@SolarMike ,  So I posted my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not just this:

```
Realised Savings prod Fixed Amount = 
 var fixedAmount = CALCULATE([Realised Savings prod], FILTER(ALL(Data), Data[UsageDate]<= DATE(2023,1,31) && Data[UsageDate]>= DATE(2023,1,1)))
 var ave = fixedAmount/30

 RETURN   IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Realised Savings prod])) && MIN(Data[UsageDate])>= DATE(2023,1,31), ave)
```

Comment: It was exactly just that.